# Hypergeometric function $_2F_1(z)$ with $|z| > 1$ in GSL

Tags: special-functions, gsl

I need to evaluate the hypergeometric function $_2F_1$ with $|z| > 1$ as in [Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric2F1.html) with GSL but the [GSL documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/specfunc.html#hypergeometric-functions) says the $_2F_1$ needs $|z| < 1$.

Is there any way I can use GSL and $_2F_1$ with $|z| > 1$?
Any reference about the subject?

Comment: Have a look at [DLMF 15.8.2](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8#E2), for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason GSL doesn't do this is that you need an analytic continuation. That's what Mathematica does. For example, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490462/convergence-of-hypergeometric-2f1-with-z-1) and [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-7091-1616-6_10.pdf). A very similar question was asked [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/calculating-hypergeometric-function-2f1-for-z-1.501956/), but they propose a roll-your-own solution.

Edit: Useful paper reference [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042700002673) per my link above (thanks for pulling it out @JoseM)

Comment: Thanks to 'A rural reader' too, the list was really helpful. This paper was useful too [The analytic continuation of the Gaussian hypergeometric function 2F1(a,b;c;z) for arbitrary parameters](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042700002673)

Comment: @JoséM, I think that you could add that and some of the details into a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please, consider this as a toy or educational code... If you want to do it yourself consider the use of a variable precision library like GMP.

In my case z > 2, so reading the paper on the forum suggested by @spencer-bryngelson, [Computation of Hypergeometric Functions](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/porterm/research/pearson_final.pdf) you get Eq.4.20 (use table 13) or you can use [DLMF 15.8.2](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8#E2) as suggested by @a-rural-reader (for me this's more clear because you can see a discontinuity if $$a - b \in \mathbb{Z}$$ see [Hypergeometric2F1](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/02/02/) too)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <gsl_sf.h>
#include <gsl_math.h>

double _2F1(double a,
            double b,
            double c,
            double z)
{
  /* a - b !€ Z */
  double bd = b - 1e-15;

  double A = (gsl_sf_gamma(bd - a)*gsl_sf_gamma(c)*pow(-z, -a))/(gsl_sf_gamma(b)*gsl_sf_gamma(c - a));
  double Fa = gsl_sf_hyperg_2F1(a, a - c + 1.0, a - bd + 1.0, 1.0/z);
  double B = (gsl_sf_gamma(a - bd)*gsl_sf_gamma(c)*pow(-z, -b))/(gsl_sf_gamma(a)*gsl_sf_gamma(c - bd));
  double Fb = gsl_sf_hyperg_2F1(bd, bd - c + 1.0, bd - a + 1.0, 1.0/z);

  return A*Fa + B*Fb;
}

int main()
{
  /* Mathematica
  Hypergeometric2F1[2., 3., 4., 5.0]
  = 0.156542 + 0.150796i
  */

  double a = 2.0;
  double b = 3.0;
  double c = 4.0;
  double z = 5.0;

  double result = _2F1(a, b, c, z);
  printf("2F1(%.1f, %.1f, %.1f, %.1f): %f\n", a, b, c, z, result);
  /* result = 0.15625*/

  /*
  Hypergeometric2F1[2., 3., 4., 10.0]
  Out[30]= 0.03985 + 0.0188496 I
  */
  z = 10.0;

  result = _2F1(a, b, c, z);
  printf("2F1(%.1f, %.1f, %.1f, %.1f): %f\n", a, b, c, z, result);
  /* result = 0.0341796875*/

  return 0;
}
```

As you can see the results are far from accurate.

If you don't want to do it yourself, I think [Arb](https://arblib.org/) seems a good choice.

Comment: Nice follow up, José.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a transformation formula. Here is how I do in R:

```
library(gsl)
Gauss2F1 <- function(a,b,c,x){
    if(x>=0 & x<1){
        hyperg_2F1(a,b,c,x)
    }else{
        hyperg_2F1(c-a,b,c,1-1/(1-x))/(1-x)^b
    }
}
```